# Add document to document library with additional column data using Powershell

Tags: powershell, sharepoint-2010, document-library

I'm trying to loop through pdf files in a directory and send them to a sharepoint document library. When I send them I would like to add the customer, invoice, etc to the list as well. Anyone have recommendations?

Answer (score 0):

Sure.  This can done fairly easily.  Here's the article I've used in the past for reference:

http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2010/09/23/use-powershell-cmdlets-to-manage-sharepoint-document-libraries.aspx

Setting metadata should be pretty easy as well, but PowerShell can't guess what a customer, invoice, etc is.  So you'll have to have some data source.  If the filename contains the data, you could split it.  If the data is in the file itself, there are some methods of getting plaintext strings out of a PDF, but it's going to be a bit harder than the first part of your request.

Let me know if I can help further with any specifics.